# Mysql Query to get a record whose date time is immediately after the current date time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an appointment Table containing following fields. I write a query like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM appointments app 
WHERE app.patient_id = 123
ORDER BY appointment_start_dt DESC;
```

```
+--+----------+--------------------+
|id|patient_id|appointment_start_dt|
+--+----------+--------------------+
|1 |123       |2014-01-18 19:10:00 |
+--+----------+--------------------+
|2 |123       |2014-01-18 12:08:00 |
+--+----------+--------------------+
|3 |123       |2014-01-17 15:00:00 |
+--+----------+--------------------+
|4 |123       |2014-01-15 11:01:00 |
+--+----------+--------------------+
|5 |123       |2014-01-11 12:30:00 |
+--+----------+--------------------+
|6 |123       |2014-01-10 04:00:01 |
+--+----------+--------------------+
```

Table has some appointments before the current date (Assume current Date Time is 2014-01-15 15:00:00) and some appointments after the current date and time against a particular Patient.
I need to fetch a single record against one patient whose appointment date is immediately come after the current date time, i.e if there are two appointment that  will come after 2014-01-17 15:00:00, I need to select the appointment which is earliest one that is 2014-01-18 12:08:00.

I really appreciate if any body help me to make this query
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try

```
SELECT * 
FROM appointments app 
where app.patient_id = 123 AND appointment_start_dt > Now()
order by appointment_start_dt ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Yes It solved the problem. I was trying to use DESC that always give me Highest date record. any How Thanks Kay Nelson.